# Python/SQL loading Error: Exceeded the memory limit of 20 MB per session for prepared statements

Tags: python, pandas, azure, pandas-to-sql

I am using Pandas to_sql to load a CSV with just about 6k rows of data. I have a very large Azure Synapse DW with more than enough capacity but i am having a problem that it will load about 1.5k rows and then fail with this out of memory error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]112007;Exceeded the memory limit of 20 MB per session for prepared statements. Reduce the number or sizeof the prepared statements. (112007) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

my code looks like this:

```
df_table.to_sql('Test_Name', engine, if_exists='replace',dtype={col_name: VARCHAR(length=100) for col_name in df_table},index=False, chunksize=1000)
```

I have tried to set a chunksize but seems to have no impact. Why is it struggling with such a tiny dataset and how can I load the full csv file?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @bbennett36 No, unfortunately not. pandas to_sql works without issues with progresql but only ever produced issues with mssql. I instead used the Copy Activity functionality in Azure Data Factory and abdonded using pandas for ingestion. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview